# Debugging strange, sudden error with SSL socket.io

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

This error did not exist before and I can't figure out what happened. The website ssl is ok, the nodejs ssl was just fine, no code was changed whatsoever, the ports opened remain the same.

Here is the print of the console logs:
[image]

I can't figure what is wrong, at all. I know this is normal to say in programming but I literally did do nothing. The server session restarted and came back as this. The ssl on the website is working well so the encryption is not *expired*. I am using version 1.4.5 on node and the client, **however**, for no reason at all, doing `npm socket.io --version` points to version 1.3.10 while I have required version 1.4.5 in my package.json. Unninstalling and installing socketio does not solve this. Does anyone have any idea on how I could debug this effectively? I've tried going to the logs but nothing is working so far.

Comment: System time incorrect? Also, check out [this page](https://aboutssl.org/fix-google-chrome-error-err_ssl_protocol_error) for some pointers on how to fix that error.